# Error \centering with \multicolumn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption[Structural properties of $5$ networks charging of the $5$ biological
functions and the global network]{\textbf{Structural properties of $5$ networks
charging of the $5$ biological functions and the global network}.
\textbf{Notes}: CCs is short for Connected Components, Clus.Coef. means
Clustering Coefficient}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{0.75cm}}{\textbf{Network}} &
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{0.75cm}}{\textbf{Nb. CCs}} &
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1.0cm}}{\textbf{Nb. Nodes}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1.50cm}}{\textbf{Nb. Clusters}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1.25cm}}{\textbf{Density}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1.25cm}}{\textbf{Avg. Deg.}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1.25cm}}{\textbf{Avg. Clus. Coef.}} \\
\midrule
MNHPC   & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 3 & 0.218 \\
Vss     & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s  & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f  & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g  & 1 & 83 & 83 & 0.039 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out    & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 2 & 0.214 \\

\midrule
Vss     & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s  & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f  & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g  & 41& 3  & 3  & 0.667 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out    & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.036 & 2 & 0.214 \\

\midrule
Vss     & 10& 70 & 70 & 0.048 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s  & 8 & 74 & 74 & 0.044 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f  & 5 & 81 & 81 & 0.040 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g  & 5 & 81 & 81 & 0.040 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out    & 5 & 82 & 82 & 0.038 & 2 & 0.214 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\label{tab:chap5-structural-properties}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I cannot debug from the piece of latex code. Do you know where is the problem?

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
 
                \par 
l.15 ...{>{\centering}p{0.75cm}}{\textbf{Network}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to load the `array` package, which defines the `>{…}` syntax for tables. However I suggest you'd rather use the `makecell` package, that allows for line breaks and common formatting in cells, with the `\thead` and `\makecell` commands.
To have boldface captions, use the `caption` package: this will save you typing twice the same caption, in boldface and in normal weight for the list of figures. Finally, I used the `threeparttable` package to typeset the note at the bottom of the table, and `siunitx` for a proper alignment of numbers in columns 2-4.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multirow, array, makecell}
```

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \captionsetup{font = bf}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{table-format = 2.0}

```
\begin{document}%

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Structural properties of 5 networks charging of the 5 biological functions and the global network}
\begin{tabular}{lSSSccc}
\toprule
\thead{Network} & {\thead{Nb.\\ CCs}} & {\thead{Nb.\\ Nodes}} & {\thead{Nb.\\ Clusters}} & \thead{Density} &\thead{Avg.\\ Deg.}& \thead{Avg.\\ Clus.\\ Coef.}
\\
\midrule
MNHPC & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 3 & 0.218 \\
Vss & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g & 1 & 83 & 83 & 0.039 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out & 1 & 92 & 92 & 0.036 & 2 & 0.214 \\
\midrule
Vss & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.037 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g & 41& 3 & 3 & 0.667 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out & 2 & 90 & 90 & 0.036 & 2 & 0.214 \\
\midrule
Vss & 10& 70 & 70 & 0.048 & 2 & 0.194 \\
Vac\_s & 8 & 74 & 74 & 0.044 & 2 & 0.205 \\
Vac\_f & 5 & 81 & 81 & 0.040 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vac\_g & 5 & 81 & 81 & 0.040 & 3 & 0.215 \\
Vgl\_out & 5 & 82 & 82 & 0.038 & 2 & 0.214 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:chap5-structural-properties}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[$ \!\! $]\textbf{Notes}: CCs is short for Connected Components, Clus.Coef. means
Clustering Coefficient
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @David Carlisle: You're right, it's unfair. You answered first for the O.P.'s question, and I only added some improvements to the table – which weren't asked for.

Comment: I'm only joking, your answer is way more complete than mine:-)

Comment: Better stealing a tick than stealing a chick? :o)

Answer (score 4):

the `>` syntax requires the `array` package, add

```
\usepackage{array}
```